# Python kivy typeerror

Tags: python, kivy, typeerror, metaclass

```
from kivy.uix.button import Button

from kivy.uix.label import Label

from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput

from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager

from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout

from kivy.uix.widget import Widget

from kivy.lang import Builder

from kivy.core.window import Window

Builder.load_file('Eng.kv')

class EngAppMenu(Screen,Window):

    pass

sm = ScreenManager()

sm.add_widget(EngAppMenu(name='menu'))

class EngApp(App):

    def build(self):

        return sm

if __name__ == '__main__':

    EngApp().run()
```

kv file:

```
# Eng.kv file:
<EngAppMenu>:

Window:
    clearcolor:rgba(1,1,1,0)
```

And I have an error:
typeerror: metaclass p: the metaclass of a derived class must be a (non-strict) subclass of the metaclasses of all its bases

How to solve it. What should I do?

Comment: What are you attempting to do with your use of `Window`? Kivy creates its `Window` for you. See the [documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable-2.0.0/api-kivy.core.window.html#module-kivy.core.window).

Comment: I wanna change window settings

Comment: How can I change window settings?

Comment: The documentation that I mentioned above shows settings that can be modified. You can access the `root_window` of your app through the `root_window` property of the `App`.

Answer (score 0):

This will likely solve the metaclass error message:

```
class MetaAppMenu(type(Screen), type(Window)): 
    pass

class EngAppMenu(Screen,Window, metaclass=MetaAppMenu):

    pass
```

However, the fact this does not work out of the box is telling in a very strong way that "Window" and "Screen"in Kivy have not been designed to work collaboratively with multiple inheritance (would it even make sense?).

So, there are ways to fix the metaclass error, but that won't fix your approach.